# How to modify elements of a range of lists in R?

Tags: r, list, lapply, purrr

Here is the example:

```
R<-vector("list",10) #a list of 10 elements
r<-rep(0,5) # each list includes this vector

#we add the vector to all lists
for(i in 1:10)
{
    R[[i]]$r=r
}

index<-c(2,3,6)
```

Now what I want to do is changing `r[1]` to `2` in all `R` lists specified by `index`. If we had an index  of size one, then the solution would be `R[[index]]$r[1]=2`. But how about when we have a range of indexes?  What would be the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: do you not want to use your loop code again? `for(i in index) R[[i]]$r[1] <- 2`

Comment: I was looking for something more efficient than a loop. Also, it would be great if you tell me a how to replace the first loop with something more efficient.

Comment: @Milad This would do the same thing as your loop: `map(1:10, ~list(r=r))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rawr for the suggestion about using `replace()`

```
library(purrr)
index<-c(2,3,6)
modify_at(R, index,~list(r=replace(.$r, 1, 2)))
```

In response to the comment below, you could replace the first element with the first element plus 2 with the following:

```
R <- modify_at(R, index,~list(r=replace(.$r, 1, .$r[1]+2)))
```

Comment: This looks good! But let's make the problem a bit more interesting. What if we want to update each `r[1]` like this `r[1]=r[1]+2` ?

Comment: @Milad I edited the answer accordingly.  I also modified the first answer to retain the initial format of all lists that get changed.